# OpenCV How can I calculate area of binary object?

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV and c++. I have black and white image after binarization. How can I calculate area of object when I have only one coordinate of point (x,y) belongs to this object??

Answer (score 2):

since it's a binary image, you can easily get the [blobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection). Once you get the blobs, you can easily calculate the blob area.
You can use [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) to get the blobs. OpenCV hasn't integrated cvBlobsLib. You can do it by yourself. But OpenCV has functionality for contours. You can use findContours to get blobs/contours and then get the area. [OpenCV - findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

[OpenCV - Structural Analysis and Shape Description](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)

You'll find information about moments, huMoments, contours, etc. Using moments, you can create your own blobs and it will also help you in getting the blob area.

Here's an Open Source framework for machine vision which uses Python bindings of OpenCV - [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/)

They have implemented a complete blob functionality using contours and moments. You can have a look.

[Blob](https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/develop/SimpleCV/Features/Blob.py)

[BlobMaker](https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/develop/SimpleCV/Features/BlobMaker.py)

It's written in Python, but you can port it to C++ and use blobs.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is very easy and should be the following:

1. [Find all contours on your image](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).
2. Cycle through all contours and [check if point is inside a contour](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest).
3. If contour is found than calculate [it's area](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contourarea#contourarea).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some kind of region growing algorithm, starting from your startpoint, incrementally adding adjacent pixels that are of the same color.

A lazy (and much slower) way to do it would be to use cv::floodFill function, setting up the pixels in your shape to a specific color, then counting the pixels in you image that have this specific color.