# Selection of central blob in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a b/w image containing a number of blobs (image below). My plan to isolate the central blob (inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316031/opencv-how-can-i-calculate-area-of-binary-object)) is:

- find the contours;
- check in which contour is the image center;
- find the area of the central blob.

The image I am working with is binary, and this is the piece of code I ended up with, to find the contours:

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

When I run the script, I get the following error: `TypeError: src data type = 0 is not supported`. Do you know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv2.threshold) should always be your first check. The error says 0 is not a valid type. You should use for example `cv2.THRESH_BINARY`as type instead of 0